# module conflict when both the older AzureRM and newer Az modules are loaded onto the same PS session

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-powershell

We are trying to change Automation account from Service principal to System manged identity. After we changed the power shell script to used System managed identity it ask for upgrade Az module and we upgrade it. after that we are getting module conflict error. Can anyone know how I can fix this module conflict issue.? how can I uninstall AzureRM module completely from automation account as we are not using this module. ( I tried to delete AzureRM module but default module not able to delete from automation account)

Service principal Code:

```
try {
    $servicePrincipalConnection = Get-AutomationConnection -Name $connectionName 
        $null = Connect-AzAccount -ServicePrincipal `
            -TenantId $servicePrincipalConnection.TenantId `
            -ApplicationId $servicePrincipalConnection.ApplicationId `
            -CertificateThumbprint $servicePrincipalConnection.CertificateThumbprint 
        Write-Output "Authenticated with Service principal." 
    }
catch {
        Write-Error -Message $_.Exception
        throw $_.Exception
      }
try {
        $smtpPasswordString = Get-AzKeyVaultSecret  -VaultName $keyVaultName -Name $smtpPasswordSecretName -AsPlainText -ErrorAction Stop
        Write-Output "Success retrieving source KeyVault Secrets" 
    }
catch {
            Write-Error -Message $_.Exception
            Write-Output "Error retrieving source KeyVault Secrets"
      }
```

System Managed Identity Code:

Note: I successfully authenticated but when it retrieve key secrets its give me module conflict error. I upgraded all Az and AzureRM modules with latest version.

```
try {
      $null =    Connect-AzAccount -Identity 
        Write-Output "Authenticated with System Identity." 
    }
catch {
        Write-Error -Message $_.Exception
        throw $_.Exception
      }
try {
        $smtpPasswordString = Get-AzKeyVaultSecret  -VaultName $keyVaultName -Name $smtpPasswordSecretName -AsPlainText -ErrorAction Stop
        Write-Output "Success retrieving source KeyVault Secrets" 
    }
catch {
            Write-Error -Message $_.Exception
            Write-Output "Error retrieving source KeyVault Secrets"
      }
```

Error return:

The error is due to module conflict when both the older AzureRM and newer Az modules are loaded onto the same PS session - these two modules are incompatible .If your executing script in an Azure sandbox , ensure no runbook is calling both Az and AzureRM modules in the same PSSession or used in the same script or runbook. To fix the issue, Create two different automation account & import the Az & Rm modules separately to them OR schedule the runbooks using Az & AzureRm modules at separate times, so as to avoid the modules in the same PSSession. If you are executing script on Hybrid worker , then uninstall Az/AzureRM module and try running the script again . Use 'Uninstall-AzModule' function to remove all Az modules as described here : https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/uninstall-az-ps?view=azps-4.6.1#uninstall-the-az-powershell-module-from-powershellget or use 'Uninstall-AzureRm' cmdlet to remove all AzureRm modules as described here : https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/uninstall-az-ps?view=azps-4.3.0#uninstall-the-azurerm-module Inner Error:System.TypeLoadException: Method 'get_SerializationSettings' in type 'Microsoft.Azure.Management.Internal.Resources.ResourceManagementClient' from assembly 'Microsoft.Azure.PowerShell.Clients.ResourceManager, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' does not have an implementation. at Microsoft.Azure.Commands.ResourceManager.Common.AzureRMCmdlet.BeginProcessing() at System.Management.Automation.Cmdlet.DoBeginProcessing() at System.Management.Automation.CommandProcessorBase.DoBegin() + CategoryInfo : NotSpecified: (:) [Write-Error], WriteErrorException + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WriteErrorException

Answer (score 0):

Error in [get_Serialization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/troubleshoot/runbooks#get-serializationsettings) settings:

> This error is probably caused by using an incomplete migration from AzureRM to Az modules in your runbook.

To solve this, you need to migrate it to AZ modules. Coming to Azure automation, it is not feasible to delete the Azure RM modules by going into modules under shared resources in the automation account and the delete option is greyed out.

[image]

***The reason for this is that you can only uninstall modules which is either installed/imported by the contributor or the admin, not the default global modules.***

Refer MS Doc for [Migration procedure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/shared-resources/modules#migrate-to-az-modules) in detail.

*After a workaround on this, I found the following way for avoiding Azure RM module conflicts in the current PS session.*

Firstly, if you want to uninstall `Azure RM` you need to use `PowerShell 5.1` version. Because Azure RM doesn't support PowerShell core `7.1` & above.

To use `uninstall-AzureRM` in Azure runbook, you need to connect Azure account in admin mode.

For that, make sure that you enabled `system identity` for your `Automation account` and add the necessary permissions under `identity -> system identity(on) -> Azure role assignments`.

Once it is done try running the below script which worked for me.

To verify if the `Azure RM` was properly uninstalled, I used the `Get-Module` command to retrieve the Azure RM list, but nothing gets printed except Az modules.

```
connect-AzAccount -Identity
Uninstall-AzureRm
Get-Module -Listavailable Az.*
Get-Module AzureRM -ListAvailable
```

[image]

Or if there is a conflict in the PS session anytime, try using
`Import-Module -Name AZ.*` and execute your script. In this way also, you can remove the conflict for the specific sessions.

*If still the issue persists, try running the scripts in different runbooks and schedule accordingly.*

Refer [github issues](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/55058) for the relevant information.

Comment: Thank you @Jahnavi for your response. Default module we are not able to delete it. Also I tried your script in new PowerShell 5.1 and try to run in automation account it gives following error. I granted system identity permission role to contributor on resource group and automation account

Comment: connect-AzAccount : Method 'get_SerializationSettings' in type 'Microsoft.Azure.Management.Internal.Resources.ResourceManagementClient' 
from assembly 'Microsoft.Azure.PowerShell.Clients.ResourceManager, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' 
does not have an implementation. At line:1 char:1 + connect-AzAccount -Identity + ~  CategoryInfo : 
NotSpecified: (:) [Connect-AzAccount], TypeLoadException + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.TypeLoadException,Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Profile.ConnectAzureRmAccountCommand

Comment: Use `import-module -Name AZ` before giving `connect-Azaccount`. @NP007

Comment: When I used import-module -Name AZ in first line of scripts and when i ran it gives below error for all AZ related modules. so far i gave error for Az.Automation module only.


Import-Module : The specified module 'Az.Automation' with version '1.7.1' was not loaded because no valid module file was found in any module directory. At C:\Modules\Global\AZ\Az.psm1:118 char:1

Comment: Have you imported Az automation module from modules blade in automation account! @NP007

Comment: yes already did still it gave error.  But I notice when I downgraded Az account module to default 2.5.3 its working without any uninstall AzureRM modules. it seems upgraded AZ modules had some issue. See comment in this link https://github.com/Azure/azure-powershell/issues/21647 (Comment on May2) previously i used latest AZ modules which cause the issue. Let me know my understating is correct or not?

Comment: if you aggreged then I can post the answer my self.